# Haxe macro - Open file with relative path

Tags: file, macros, haxe

I'm writing a macro that needs to open a directory which is in the same folder as my macro class. The problem is that I need to be able to do the same thing, without the need to be aware about macro's folder.

My question is simple, is there a way to open the FileSystem in macro, in the current directory.

e.g :
a (b (Macro.hx, c (...) ) )

I need to open "c" directly when I'm running macro methods from "Macro.hx"

If you have an idea, Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a function like this inside of a macro:

```
    static function loadFileAsString(path:String) {
        try {
            var p = haxe.macro.Context.resolvePath(path);
            return sys.io.File.getContent(p);
        }
        catch(e:Dynamic) {
            return haxe.macro.Context.error('Failed to load file $path: $e', Context.currentPos());
        }
    }
```

Basically, `Context.resolvePath` will resolve a path relative to all of your class paths.  So if your macro is in a file `my/package/MyMacro.hx`, and you want to load `my/package/MyMacroData.json`, you could use:

```
haxe.macro.Context.resolvePath( 'my/package/MyMacroData.json' );
```

This will check every classpath in your build - including any haxelibs etc, so it will find your file, but it will be possible to "shadow" it, by having a file in the same package/location but in a different class path or haxelib, so try to use a unique package/name so this doesn't happen by accident.

But it should work fine for you, I use it in my [compiletime library](https://github.com/jasononeil/compiletime/blob/master/src/CompileTime.hx#L98) if you want to look at an example implementation.  I've linked to the function with the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I need. I already tried resolvePath without success, because I was trying with my.package.MyMacroData.json and not with '/'.... I'm stupid ^^" Thank you :)